# SVG image shows over header with bigger zIndex than the image

Tags: reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css, z-index

I am making a website in react and I created a header and body section. When I added SVG image it was over the header, even though header had z index of 20 while image had lower. Image is supposed to go partly behind the header and not infront of it. I am using **tailwind** with react

**Header Code:**

```
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMobileMenu = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
  };

  return (
    <section className='z-[20]'>
      <header className="bg-[#222222] shadow-md text-white border-b border-black2 z-[20]">
        <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center p-4 relative my-auto z-[10]">
          {/* Logo */}
          <a href="#" className="flex items-center space-x-3 z-[10]">
            <h1 className='transform md:scale-[2.2] scale-[1.5] translate-x-10 font-semibold '>GetFit</h1>
            {/* <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Gym Logo" className="h-8 justify-center" /> */}
          </a>

          {/* Navigation */}
          <nav className="hidden md:flex justify-end space-x-7 flex-grow z-[10]">
            <a href="#home" className="text-white hover:text-primary transition-colors font-semibold text-lg link-hover">
              Home
            </a>
            <a href="#pricing" className="text-white hover:text-primary transition-colors font-semibold text-lg link-hover">
              Pricing
            </a>
            <a href="#testimonials" className="text-white hover:text-primary transition-colors font-semibold text-lg link-hover">
              Testimonials
            </a>
            <a href="#contact" className="text-white hover:text-primary transition-colors font-semibold text-lg link-hover">
              Contact
            </a>
          </nav>

          {/* Mobile Menu Button */}
          <button
            className="md:hidden ml-auto focus:outline-none"
            onClick={toggleMobileMenu}
          >
            <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16m-7 6h7"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>

          {/* Mobile Menu */}
          <div
            className={`md:hidden fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-[#222222CC] transform transition-transform ease-in-out duration-300 ${isMobileMenuOpen ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full'
              }`}
          >
            <div className="flex justify-end p-4">
              <button
                className="text-white focus:outline-none"
                onClick={toggleMobileMenu}
              >
                <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <nav className="flex flex-col items-center">
              <a href="#home" className="text-white py-2 px-4 hover:text-primary">
                Home
              </a>
              <a href="#pricing" className="text-white py-2 px-4 hover:text-primary">
                Pricing
              </a>
              <a href="#testimonials" className="text-white py-2 px-4 hover:text-primary">
                Testimonials
              </a>
              <a href="#contact" className="text-white py-2 px-4 hover:text-primary">
                Contact
              </a>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </section>

  );
};

export default Header;
```

**Hero Section code:**

```
import React from 'react';

const SectionHero = () => {
    return (
        <section className='max-h-[1011px]'>



            <div className='columns-1 md:columns-2'>
                <div className='w-full h-[55rem]'>
                    <div className='md:pl-[8rem] sm:pl-[0.5rem] mt-[6rem]'>
                        <h1 className='text-white sm:text-title font-[600] leading-[3rem] text-[2.5rem] sm:leading-[5rem]'>It's <span className='text-primary'>Time</span></h1>
                        <h1 className='text-white sm:text-title font-[600] leading-[3rem] text-[2.5rem] sm:leading-[5rem]'>Get <span className='text-primary'>Fit</span></h1>
                        <h1 className='text-white sm:text-title font-[600] leading-[3rem] text-[2.5rem] sm:leading-[5rem]'>Improve <span className='text-primary'>your</span> life</h1>
                        <p className='text-white pt-12 font-[200] w-[80%] text-[22px]'>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                            elit. Nullam dapibus, nunc nec consectetur pellentesque,
                            turpis ex facilisis velit, at eleifend neque
                        </p>
                        <div className='flex mt-[3rem] space-x-8'>
                            <a
                                href="#section-work"
                                className={`text-center inline-block bg-primary rounded-[10px] py-4 px-7 text-white font-semibold text-[1rem] transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2`}
                            >
                                Join Now
                            </a>
                            <a
                                href="#section-work"
                                className={`text-center inline-block bg-none border-primary border-2 rounded-[10px] py-4 px-7 text-white font-semibold text-[1rem] transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out hover:-translate-y-2`}
                            >
                                Contact
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className='w-full h-[55rem] relative'>

                    <div className="flex justify-end">
                            <img src="/bg-light.svg" alt="Background Light" className=" scale-[1.5] transform" />
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default SectionHero;
```

You can see how it looks and how it is supposed to look:

[image: How it looks]

[image: How it is supposed to look]

All I tried is change z index, but nothing happened